# How to generate random graphs in R?

Tags: r

I want to generate **random** transportation graphs in R with **n vertices**.

The graphs should be **bi-oriented** and **connected** ( there is usually a link between 2 vertices ) without **" Loops"**.

A loop in graph theory is an oriented edge whose origin and end are combined ( like B in the picture ).

[image]

In addition , the edges valuation should be **random & strictly positive**  .

I found that this could be possible using "Igraph" package.

I tried :

```
library("igraph")
n=10 # number of vertices
g=sample_bipartite(n, 5, p=.1) # This generates a graph 
distances(g)
```

The problem is that the generated graph don't matches the conditions above.
Thank you for help !

Comment: Could you be more clear about what you want it do that it does not...

Comment: @sconfluentus I want to generate a random bipartite graph where the distance between two adjacent edges is stricly positive . In addition , the graph should be without loops and should be connected ( there is usually a way to go from any vertice "i" to another vertice "j" ).

Comment: This is the meaning of loops in the graph theory : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(graph_theory)

Comment: So, you are getting the self-connected loops. I understand what you are looking for, I was just not sure what you were getting because you did not include output

Comment: @sconfluentus . My problem is also with distance beteween two adjacent vertices ( should be  > 0 ) .

Comment: Thank you a lot if you could help !

Comment: Have you tried supplying `type="Gnm"` and `directed=true` I think that by choosing that type with directed it might eliminate the loops

Comment: The graph should be pibartite , not directed.

Comment: try supplying the "Gnm" to see if that fixes things, you can see how that works here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model. I think the problem is that this method was not meant to synthesize the type of graph you want...this should explain it.

Comment: I still have a problem with the distance between vertices , i think i will try to generate a random distance matrix , then i will create the bipartite graph.

Comment: Thank you a lot anyway !

Comment: there should never be a loop in a bipartite graph, since all edges must be between an edge of type 1 and edge of type 2. A loop in nonsensical for bipartite graphs and `sample_bipartite()` should never produce one. If you want a matrix of distances where all off-diagonals are positive (non-infinite), bump up your value for `p` to greater than 0.5

Comment: @paqmo , i understand . Thank you all !